# Need my array to conform to a particular type in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have the following struct that I need to work with:

```
import Foundation

protocol QueryValueConvertible {

    func itemsWith(name: String) -> [URLQueryItem]
}

struct QueryList : QueryValueConvertible {

    var elements: [(String, QueryValueConvertible)]

    init(elements: [(String, QueryValueConvertible)]) {
        self.elements = elements
    }

    var isEmpty: Bool {
        return elements.isEmpty
    }

    var percentEncodedQuery: String {
        let allowedCharacters = QueryList.percentEncodedQueryAllowedCharacters
        return items.map { (item) -> String in
            guard let encodedName = item.name.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowedCharacters) else {
                return ""
            }
            if let value = item.value, let encodedValue = value.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowedCharacters) {
                return encodedName + "=" + encodedValue
            } else {
                return encodedName
            }
        }.joined(separator: "&")
    }

    var items: [URLQueryItem] {
        return elements.flatMap { (name, value) -> [URLQueryItem] in
            return value.itemsWith(name: name)
        }
    }

    func itemsWith(name: String) -> [URLQueryItem] {
        let prefix = name
        guard !elements.isEmpty else {
            return [URLQueryItem(name: "\(name)[]", value: nil)]
        }
        return elements.flatMap { (suffix, value) -> [URLQueryItem] in
            let name = "\(prefix)[\(suffix)]"
            return value.itemsWith(name: name)
        }
    }

    private static let percentEncodedQueryAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet = { () -> CharacterSet in
        // We are far more conservative than NSURLComponents because nobody implements RFC 3986.
        // HTML5 allows the following restricted set of characters to appear in query.
        // cf: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#application/x-www-form-urlencoded-encoding-algorithm
        let characters = NSMutableCharacterSet()
        characters.addCharacters(in: NSRange(location: 0x2a, length: 1))  // *
        characters.addCharacters(in: NSRange(location: 0x2d, length: 1))  // -
        characters.addCharacters(in: NSRange(location: 0x2e, length: 1))  // .
        characters.addCharacters(in: NSRange(location: 0x30, length: 10)) // 0-9
        characters.addCharacters(in: NSRange(location: 0x41, length: 26)) // A-Z
        characters.addCharacters(in: NSRange(location: 0x5f, length: 1))  // _
        characters.addCharacters(in: NSRange(location: 0x61, length: 26)) // a-z
        return characters as CharacterSet
    }()
}

extension QueryList : ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral {

    init(dictionaryLiteral elements: (String, QueryValueConvertible)...) {
        self.elements = elements
    }

    init<S : Sequence>(_ elements: S)
        where S.Iterator.Element == (String, QueryValueConvertible)
    {
        self.elements = Array(elements)
    }
}

extension QueryList : ExpressibleByArrayLiteral {

    init(arrayLiteral elements: QueryValueConvertible...) {
        self.elements = elements.enumerated().map { (index, value) in (String(index), value) }
    }

    init<S : Sequence>(_ elements: S)
        where S.Iterator.Element : QueryValueConvertible
    {
        self.elements = elements.enumerated().map { (index, value) in (String(index), value) }
    }
}

func + (lhs: QueryList, rhs: QueryList) -> QueryList {
    return QueryList(elements: lhs.elements + rhs.elements)
}

func += (lhs: inout QueryList, rhs: QueryList) {
    lhs = QueryList(elements: lhs.elements + rhs.elements)
}

extension String : QueryValueConvertible {

    func itemsWith(name: String) -> [URLQueryItem] {
        return [URLQueryItem(name: name, value: self)]
    }
}

extension Int : QueryValueConvertible {

    func itemsWith(name: String) -> [URLQueryItem] {
        return [URLQueryItem(name: name, value: String(self))]
    }
}

extension Bool : QueryValueConvertible {

    func itemsWith(name: String) -> [URLQueryItem] {
        return [URLQueryItem(name: name, value: self ? "true" : "false")]
    }
}
```

In a separate class I have the following code:

```
var sampleData = [
    "foo": someString,
    "bar": anotherString    
] as QueryList

let myDict: [String: Bool] = ["example": true]
var myArray = [[String:Any]]()
myArray.append(myDict)
sampleData += ["myData": myArray]// this is where the error is occurring.
```

I am getting the following compile time error:

```
"Value of type [[String: Any]] does not conform to expected dictionary value type "QueryValueConvertible"
```

What I'm trying to do is submit a dictionary with a key/value pair of "String" to "Bool", contained inside an Array.  This array in turn is referenced also be a key of type "String".

Comment: Maybe `] as [QueryList]`?

Comment: @i_am_jorf Could you please clarify?

Comment: Hi syedfa. I've noticed your posts are rather chatty, and perhaps other users just have not previously commented to request future brevity. I notice that you've added "Dear developers" to 58 of your posts, and "thanks in advance" to 182 of them. Editors will generally remove those things over time, so if they don't go into posts to start with, you will be saving volunteers from some extra work. Thanks.

Comment: @halfer  Thanks for the heads up.  I'll keep that in mind for future posts.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the type of myArray from [[String: Any]] to [[String: QueryValueConvertible]] when you declare it. 
Alternatively you could initialise it to the same effect like this:

```
var myArray: [[String: QueryValueConvertible]] = [myDict]
```